# How do we perform repeated function calls with arguments in incremental orders?

Tags: python, csv

I have devised a code which works, but it is too tedious to repeat the code multiple times.

Let's say my function is
`def merge_data(first_excel, sheet_name, second_csv, outfile): ....`

and all my functions calls were

`merge_data(first_excel,'AAA-001','AAA001_Mirae_Performance_Lot(2022)_N1.2.csv','TFM_AAA001_merged_file.csv')`
`merge_data(first_excel,'AAA-002','AAA002_Mirae_Performance_Lot(2022)_N1.2.csv','TFM_AAA002_merged_file.csv')`
`merge_data(first_excel,'AAA-003','AAA003_Mirae_Performance_Lot(2022)_N1.2.csv','TFM_AAA003_merged_file.csv')`
`merge_data(first_excel,'AAA-004','AAA004_Mirae_Performance_Lot(2022)_N1.2.csv','TFM_AAA004_merged_file.csv')`

...

`merge_data(first_excel,'AAA-100','AAA100Mirae_Performance_Lot(2022)_N1.2.csv','TFM_AAA100merged_file.csv')`

`merge_data(first_excel,'BBB-001','BBB001Mirae_Performance_Lot(2022)_N1.2.csv','TFM_BBB001merged_file.csv')`
`merge_data(first_excel,'BBB-002','BBB002Mirae_Performance_Lot(2022)_N1.2.csv','TFM_BBB002merged_file.csv')`
`merge_data(first_excel,'BBB-003','BBB003Mirae_Performance_Lot(2022)_N1.2.csv','TFM_BBB003merged_file.csv')`

...

`merge_data(first_excel,'BBB-100','BBB100Mirae_Performance_Lot(2022)_N1.2.csv','TFM_BBB100merged_file.csv')`

I am not going to write each line of code 100 plus times. Since the argument slightly differs, is there a way to make the function call much faster and not use too much lines of code? Thank you.

AAA and BBB stands for different models of machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested loop to iterate over the model and file number:

```py
model = ['AAA', 'BBB']
numbers = range(1, 101)
for m in model:
    for n in numbers:
        sheet_name = f'{m}-{n:03d}'
        second_csv = f'{m}{n:03d}_Mirae_Performance_Lot(2022)_N1.2.csv'
        outfile = f'TFM_{m}{n:03d}_merged_file.csv'
        merge_data(first_excel, sheet_name, second_csv, outfile)
```

Comment: This works perfectly, though you are missing an underscore _merged and _Mirae! Thank you. Wanna ask what does {n:03d} means?

Comment: @FloraTrace good to hear - I've corrected those typos. `{n:03d}` tells python to format the value of `n` as a 3 digit number with leading `0`s where necessary (so `5` => `005`, `12` => `012`)

Comment: See for more information https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting